# How to set Weight in java code

Tags: android, android-layout

in my xml-code I set in every View a weight value.

Now i need to change run-time the value in my java code.
I found only the setWeightSum function.
There is a function to set the layout_weight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp= new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                             LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                             LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, layout_weight);

 view.setLayoutParams(lp);
```